# Host external website page on my html page without server code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i am trying to achieve is this:

Host an external website page on my html page without any server side code, and fetch a particular html element from that page using Jquery.

The approach i have taken is that:
i have a iframe object on my page which has the href set to the external webpage.but when i try to access the content of the external webpage it give me "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: " error

any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Because of policies you **cannot** do this. It is simply a security issue. The only way to solve this is to allow it from the host domain, and even then you might run into issues. Sorry, you are trying to do something that's not allowed by browsers because of misuse.

Comment: This is a security feature specifically designed to block people like you. Might as well ask how to avoid policemen when you just want to get some jewellery. If you think you have a valid claim to the data, you can ask the host to allow you access. Or you can use a server script to fetch the data for you.

Comment: @Amadan that's a bit of an odd analogy. Making a request to a third party site programmatically is not inherently wrong, it's just blocked in JS for security reasons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Both are security. One for jewellers', one for the target host's (and consequently the hosts' clients). The main issue with cross-server client requests is the fact they are not traceable like the server ones are - if you have a server issuing requests you don't like you can block its IP, but all the clients of a given target host will have different IPs and there is no way to identify which source host is responsible. Sure there are other concerns too, but there is a reason balaklavas are not allowed in banks, even if you are wearing it legitimately to stave off the cold.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in client-side JS due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikiepedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - as you've discovered via that error message.

To achieve what you need you would have to make the request at the server-side. You could then make the request to the local server through JS to get the result you require.